# Connect to Azure SQL on Private Link using Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I would like to know, is there any way to connect to the Azure SQL server configured using Private endpoint via Azure DevOps. I have a Azure SQL database deployment task which is not able to connect to the SQL server since the server is configured using private endpoint.

I would like to know the way if any, to connect to the Azure SQL Server configured using private endpoint via Azure DevOps.

Any lead would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview#use-cases-of-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).

> Clients can connect to the Private endpoint from the same VNet, peered VNet in same region, or via VNet-to-VNet connection across regions.
>
> Additionally, clients can connect from on-premises using ExpressRoute, private peering, or VPN tunneling. Below is a simplified diagram showing the common use cases.

You can create a self-hosted agent on the azure SQL server VM, or on an Azure VM which is connected to the same VNet. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps to create self-hosted agent.

You can also create a self-hosted agent on your local machines. And using ExpressRoute, private peering, or VPN tunneling to connect to the Private Endpoint. For more information, check the document [Connecting from an on-premises environment over VPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview#connecting-from-an-on-premises-environment-over-vpn)

Then you can run your pipeline on the self-hosted agent by setting the [pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#pool) to your private agent pool which hosts the self-hosted agent. Your pipeline should be able to connect to the SQL server, since the agent machine is configured to connect to the Private Endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

There could be other easier ways but one way possibility could be is using a self hosted agent at on-premise which has got access to the Private endpoint.

Comment: Hi Shaswata, thanks for your reply. Could you please explain a little bit as I have no idea about that.